# Как перезакрыть вопрос как дубликат?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

Появились тут желающие позакрывать вопросы по литературе.

Собственно вопрос: если некоторый вопрос закрывается с формулировкой "не по теме" или какой-либо другой, то есть ли возможность закрыть его заново с формулировкой "дубликат" после появления (или нахождения) эталонного ответа?

Естественно, имеется в виду более простая возможность, чем набрать 5 голосов на переоткрытие и потом снова 5 голосов на закрытие.

Comment: А что, за такие действия идет репа в основном сайте? Если так, то понятно, почему толпа новичков занимается всей этой ерундой.

Comment: @avp - вроде за тревоги и правки только при низком рейтинге что-то дают. А остальным только значок заработать.

Comment: @Qwertiy за тревогу не дают ничего. толко медальки

Comment: можно просто ссылку добавить на дубликат. Хотя, чтобы автоматическое перенаправление работало, необходимо как дубликат закрыть.

Comment: либо, при наличии золотого знака по одной из меток в вопросе, можно дубликатить/руздубликативать за один раз. А не, с другим переоткрытиями не прокатит

Comment: @Grundy, если закрыт не как дубликат, то золотой знак не подействует для переоткрытия.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, я уже понял, и дописал в предыдущем комментарии :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

сдедует отметить вопрос тровогой вида «требутеся вмешательство модератора» и соответствующей формулировкой.

---

переписал ответ из комментария, чтобы вопрос не висел неотвеченным.

Comment: Все верно. Вешайте тревогу.