# Вопрос-аудит считает, что вопросы-списки о рекомендации книг и внешних ресурсов являются on-topic

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, очередь-проверок

Для проверки мне был показан закрытым вопрос:
[Книги и учебные ресурсы по PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458485/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-php)

я проголосовал "оставить закрытым", так как [существует консенсус в сообществе, что только канонические вопросы подобного плана могут существовать (или вообще в описании меток следует их переместить)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/623/23044) и все остальные должны быть закрыты и соответственно, *если такой вопрос уже закрыт, то его следует оставить закрытым* (канонический вариант не был бы закрыт — модераторы должны lock ставить на такие вопросы).

Подобные вопросы не должны показываться в качестве аудита.

Comment: Кстати, этот вопрос общий. Он и в проверке был как общий?

Comment: не помню -- это не имеет значения.

Answer (score 3):

Неправильные аудиты будут, вы ничего с этим не можете поделать. Всегда будут заплюсованные оффтопичные вопросы, всегда будут заминусованные онтопичные вопросы: модерация не всесильна, модерация подвержена мнению толпы, модерация не может перелопатить несколько лет существования более мягких правил.

Соответственно, всегда будут проваленные аудиты, и вы тоже ничего не можете с этим поделать. Робот, отбирающий вопросы и ответы для проверок, не может быть умнее толпы, потому что его расчёты полностью полагаются на её мнение.

Отсюда приходим к ключевому вопросу:

## Что делать, если аудит провален, и я с этим не согласен?

Для начала: есть ли последствия?

#### а) Вы забанены

Обратититесь к модератору, объясните ситуацию. Историю ваших проваленных аудитов просмотрят и, если не найдут криминала, права на ревью вернут. Учтите, что могут посмотреть не только на проваленные аудиты, но и на всю историю ревью.

#### б) Вы не забанены

Ничего делать не надо. Редкие проваленные аудиты — это нормально. Система ошибается, мнения отличаются. Порог проваленных аудитов установлен не на единице как раз по той причине, что небольшое количество разногласий допустимо.

И в качестве бонуса:

## Как сказать системе, что вы не согласны с её мнением?

Проголосуйте за пост не так, как единогласно проголосовала толпа. Если у поста только плюсы, и он был сочтён системой качественным, то можно заминусовать, проголосовать за закрытие, кинуть флаг — совершить любое действие, которое скажет, что вы считаете пост низкокачественным. После этого этот пост больше не будет предлагаться другим пользователям в качестве аудита.

То же самое верно и для противоположного случая: если вопрос заминусован или закрыт, то поставьте плюсик или проголосуйте за открытие, если считаете пост достойным спасения.

P. S. Эти действия следует совершать только в случае, если вы правы. Если вы неправы, то надо не исправлять аудиты, а покаяться. Пояснение добавлено по рекомендации @Qwertiy.

Comment: Голосовать исключительно ради влияния на систему ловушек кажется мне принципиально неверным подходом. А вот с первой частью ответа согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если вы не согласны с мнением большинства, то решение относительно качества вы **уже** приняли, и оно **уже** противоречит большинству. Я лишь предлагаю выразить это решение в конкретном действии, а не просто пропускать кривой аудит.

Comment: Возможно, но ответ прозвучал несколько по-иному. К тому же, конкретно в случае из вопроса, ставить минус эталонному вопросу по литературе - это явно не мнение _по вопросу_, это мнение по категории вопросов, _кроме конкретно этого вопроса_. Т. е. минус тут явно неуместен, тревога - тоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy Постойте, есть два варианта. Или ОП принял канонический вопрос за неканонический, то есть *ошибся*, или ОП правильно определил неканонический вопрос, но система сочла его качественным, тогда вопрос следует *закрыть*. Я описываю конкретно второй случай, то есть когда мнение системы расходится с мнением юзера, и юзер *прав*. В этом случае надо принять действия. В случае неканонического вопроса — проголосовать за закрытие. Никаких "неуместных" голосов или "мнений о категориях" не наблюдаю. Конкретно в этом случае имеет место быть *ошибка* юзера, поэтому "голосовать против" не надо.

Comment: Вот это и надо уточнить в своём ответе. А то он звучит как "не хочешь больше видеть вопрос в аудите - поставь ему другую реакцию независимо от мнения о нём".

Comment: @Qwertiy Вы предлагаете сделать приписку "Эти действия следует совершать только в случае, если вы правы"? %)

Comment: Ага, только формулировку придумать для начала :D

Comment: @Qwertiy Держите. :)

Comment: Теперь держи плюсик :)

Answer (score 2):

С другой стороны, неканонические должны быть закрыты как дубликаты. Так что найдя канонический вопрос (чтобы указать его в [тревоге](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1564/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82)), надо было заметить, что это он и есть.

В общем, неплохая так ловушка получилась :)
Может, пусть остаётся?
От любителей закрывать всё с неверными причинами должно помочь.

---

Не думаю, что система может сама ставить дубликат. Т. е., вероятно, вопрос не показывался как копия. Когда видишь такой вопрос надо:

1. Открыть [перечень эталонных ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
2. Найти в нём эталонный вопрос.
3. Выставить проверяемому вопросу тревогу, что требуется вмешательство модератора для перезакрытия как дубликат, со ссылкой на эталонный вопрос.
4. Оставить вопрос закрытым.

Что должно пойти не так в случае ловушки?

3. *Эталонный и проверяемый вопрос одинаковы.*
4. Ловушка раскрыта, Открыть.

Что ещё может пойти не так?

2. *Вопроса нет в списке эталонных.*
3. Оставить закрытым.
4. Проверка не пройдена (ну и не страшно).
5. Дополнить список эталонных ответов (а это полезно).

Таким образом, во всех случаях эта проверка была полезна.

Comment: вопрос не стоял -- "закрыть" или "не закрыть". Вопрос был "оставить закрытым" или "открыть" -- и подобные вопросы ([согласно мнению сообщества](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623/23044)) должны оставаться закрытыми (я уже не помню как дубликат чего он показывался).

Comment: @jfs, ссылку посмотрел? Такие вопросы должны быть _перезакрыты_ как дубликаты, для чего нужно поставить тревогу модератору. Логично, что в ней надо указать ссылку на эталонный вопрос. И опа - они одинаковы - значит что-то тут не то.

Comment: @jfs, для того, чтобы помнить, есть [список эталонных ответов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/Книги-и-другие-материалы-для-обучения).

Comment: Вы понимаете, что во время проверки вопрос закрытым показывался?  Я не помню дубликатом чего он показывался (если вообще как дубликат показывался [(здесь не показывается, может модератор может сказать)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/41841)) -- или Вы считаете что он показывался как дубликат самого себя? Дёргать модераторов, чтобы перезакрывать дубликаты, без явного их согласия (которое я не вижу), не хорошо (даже, если бы я бы подумал об этом)

Comment: @jfs, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @jfs, если не ошибаюсь, там кого-то из модераторов был комментарий, из которого сделали общий ответ.

Comment: Во (2) случае я не вижу, почему следует открыть (правильное решение не должно позволять закрыть канонический вопрос в принципе -- это аргумент, чтобы переместить подобные вопросы в описания меток), но допустим для простоты что это так. Остаются (1) и (3) случаи, когда вопрос остаётся закрытым -- аудит провален -- цель аудита, проверять проверяющих, если аудит верные действия считает неверными, то это бракованный аудит.

Comment: @jfs, первый случай с проваленным аудитом невозможен. Каким образом у неэталонного вопроса будет достаточный рейтинг, чтобы попасть в аудит? В случае 2 голос ставится за открыть, т. к. проверяемый уже понял, что это аудит и какой ответ в нём является ожидаемым. В случае 3 да, нехорошо, что аудит провален, но польза в виде дополнения списка эталонных ответов, на мой взнляд, это перевешивает. Ведь за один (и даже за несколько) проваленных проверок ничего не сделают.

Comment: мы обсуждаем строго вопросы-аудиты (посмотрите на заголовок, я не спросил, что делать с вопросами-списками вообще, а только с вопросами-списками, которые аудит считает нужно открыть), поэтому если по Вашему какой-то вопрос никогда не будет вопросом-аудитом, то не следует его обсуждать здесь (можно упомянуть, если это как-то поможет с вопросами-списками, которые действительно появляются в аудите).

Comment: Такой вопрос может попасть в очередь. Я привёл действия, которые с ним надо сделать в этом случае. И два возможных отклонения от этого набора в случае, если попавшийся вопрос был именно аудитом. В одном из них становится ясно, что это был аудит, в другом нет, но он достаточно редкий.