# Возможны ли "служебные метки" с Меты (вроде [важное]) на основном сайте?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

> tl;dr in English: can we have restricted tags (only addable/removable by moderators, like [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)) on the main website, not Meta?

Мы намедни в чате ([начало](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39616118#39616118)) обсуждали использование меток, которые **должны существовать**, но **использовать рядовым участникам не следует**.

И я [вспомнил](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39616599#39616599), что здесь, на Мете, уже существуют метки, добавлять и удалять которые могут лишь модераторы. Среди них [важное](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5), [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), [статус-отклонено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be), [статус-запланировано](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be), [статус-не-воспроизводится](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f). Похожим образом работает и метка [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) на основном сайте, но не уверен, тем же ли механизмом она ограничена.

#### Возможно ли придать это же свойство метке [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) на *основном* сайте?

[Даже канонические вопросы с нею считаются оффтопиком для сайта](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1751/181100) и существуют у нас лишь в порядке [объявленного сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/181100) исключения. StackOverflow как платформа плохо подходит для них, но исторически сложилось, что сюда с такими вопросами часто приходят. И хотя в описании метки явно изложена просьба новых вопросов с этой меткой не задавать, действует она не на всех.

Мы [ранее договорились](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/181100), что все вопросы по этой метке, не являющиеся каноническими, следует закрывать. А также де-факто и удалять, поскольку ничего нового по сравнению с каноническими они не добавляют. **Возможно, стоит пресечь их появление вовсе, запретив участникам создание вопросов с меткой [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8)?** Если браться за новый канонический вопрос, можно попросить модератора поставить эту метку. Таких вопросов немного, нагрузки модераторам это практически не добавит.

***Или, возможно, не стоит этого делать?** В ответ на вопрос я ожидаю услышать ответ от администрации о технической возможности это осуществить, или ответы от любых участников, объясняющие, почему это может быть нежелательно.*

---

#### Возможно ли придать это же свойство метке [оффтопик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%84%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba) на основном сайте?

На данный момент её не существует вовсе (что хорошо!), но её можно было бы использовать для заблокированных вопросов, которые больше нечем отметить, т. к. метки исключительного оффтопика постепенно удаляются с сайта. Система при механическом удалении меток оставляет метку [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), которую простым
<s>смертным</s> участникам использовать запрещено. Не знаю, разрешено ли модераторам.

Но создание такой метки без ограничения доступа к ней потянет на сайт оффтопик.

Хотя для этой конкретной цели, возможно, годится и сама [untagged](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), если модераторы **могут** её ставить.

---

#### В общем случае

Такое ограничение можно было бы использовать как механизм пожёстче указания в описании "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ" / "НЕ ЗАДАВАЙТЕ НОВЫХ ВОПРОСОВ ПО ЭТОЙ МЕТКЕ". Сколько таких меток существует, стоит изучить.

Comment: А ответа всё нет...

Comment: @Aid явных аргументированных возражений тоже не поступило. Это, на мой взгляд, уже неплохо.

Comment: Я имел ввиду ответ официального шерифа.

Comment: Подобные предложения надо на MSE писать.

Answer (score 7):

Да, как оказалось, введение специальных меток на основном сайте технически возможно.

---

*Обновление*

Как оказалось, можно в теории, но не всегда на практике. Сейчас продолжаю общаться с ребятами, будем искать оптимальный подход. В текущая реализация движка, как я понял, не позволяет легко задавать произвольную метку как служебную. Отпишусь сразу, как станет более понятна прикладная сторона вопроса.

*Обновление*

Задать такие метки нельзя в общем случае. Добавление служебных меток на основном сайте — это, по–сути, хак, «костыль» и должен быть очень развернуто и обосновано аргументирован (на сколько я помню, служебные метки чуть–ли не в коде прописаны).

Comment: Так давайте же введём!

Comment: @alexolut Ага, надо бы попробовать.

Comment: Нас обманули ... расходимся!

Answer (score -1):

Но ведь сейчас любой желающий может создать эталонный вопрос с ответом. А если метка будет доступна только модераторам, то мы такую возможность потеряем.

Плюс, в данный момент есть вопросы, закрытые как дубликты - получается, они тоже получат красную метку, что несколько неправильно.

Comment: Если вопрос действительно станет эталонным, можно и модератора немного потревожить для добавления метки. Не считаю этот какой-то проблемой. Дубликаты далеко не всегда получают те метки, которые имеются на оригинальных сообщениях.

Comment: @alexolut, дубликат с темой "что почитать" без метки книги?)

Comment: В таком дубликате пользы нет. Его следует удалить. Т.е. метки не важны.

Comment: @alexolut, а если он с ответами?

Comment: При наличии эталонного вопроса хорошие ответы можно перенести в него. Вообще, это проблема, когда появляются ответы до того, как вопрос закрывается как "дубликат".

Comment: @alexolut, но ведь вопрос может быть и старым. Ты как будто только появление новых рассматриваешь.

Comment: Со старых тоже можно перенести в эталонный.

Comment: Я ж даже в вопросе об этом написал, ну. *"Если браться за новый канонический вопрос, можно попросить модератора поставить эту метку."* А вот что уже отмеченные ею вопросы надо изучить перед преобразованием, мысль хорошая.