# Удаляются ли метки с ресурса?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Вижу метку [andoid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andoid) с описанием под [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). Хотелось бы подать тревогу для удаления этой метки, но, видимо, такой функции нет.

Или например метка [интерлиньяж](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%8f%d0%b6) - сначала думал, что такого слова вообще не существует :D, но как оказалось это межстрочный интервал. Но с этой меткой всего один вопрос на ru.stackoverflow, вряд ли кто-то в поисковике будет вбивать "Ошибка с интерлиньяжем".

Или существуют метки такие как [интернет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82), где капсом написано *не использовать* - зачем тогда эти метки держать на ресурсе?

Comment: Проблема этого сайта не в метках самих по себе, а в том что любое редактирование поднимает вопрос на главную страницу. Это вынуждает участников использовать костыли (типа метку с опечаткой синомизировать к основной, как вы верно заметили про andoid), вместо простого и логичного "взять и удалить метку с вопросов", чтобы не флудить на главную страницу

Comment: @VadimTagil Нет никакой проблемы с главной страницей )

Comment: @VadimTagil и метку с опечаткой синонимизировать к основной — это не костыль, а очень удобный способ. Она и в будущем тогда будет заменяться, не придётся снова переставлять.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Удобность способа не делает его не костылем. Правильная система должна при попытке создания метки, отличающейся от существующей на одну букву, выводить предупреждение. Да и вообще, процесс создания метки должен быть чуть сложнее, чем просто ввести слово в поле (метка это все-таки существенный элемент сайта)

Comment: @VadimTagil отгадайте, на сколько букв отличаются [tag:cpp] и [tag:сpp]?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Если вы про "це-р-р" русскими буквами, то это особый случай, который должен идти в черный список, а уж точно не в синонимы cpp, LOL.

Comment: @VadimTagil ну почему же. Вариант «русская-с + +» довольно часто использовался, и сейчас это синоним [tag:c++].

Comment: @NickVolynkin может я что-то не понимаю, но "русская-с + + " отличается от "english-c + +" одной буквой - см. мой комментарий выше. А "р", в отличии от "с" не совпадает на клавиатуре с латинским аналогом

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Опечатки нужно синонимизировать, а не удалять

Если две метки обозначают одно и то же, то одну из них нужно выбрать основной, а другую — [назначить синонимом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Andoid и android уже синонимизированы...

Метку [andoid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andoid) к метке [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [синонимизировали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) больше двух лет назад:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## ... но вы можете предложить другие синонимы

Чтобы навести порядок в метках, тревоги ставить не нужно.
Лучше [предложите синоним](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms) самостоятельно:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За это даже дают довольно редкий [знак «Синонимист»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer).

Если вам не хватает репутации — [напишите про опечатку в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

## Описание синонима — это описание основной метки

В подсказке к метке [andoid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/andoid) вы видели настоящее описание метки [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

- Метка-синоним получает описание от основной метки.
- Ссылка на страницу синонима редиректится на страницу основной метки.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Синоним заменяется при редактировании

- Когда метку-синоним ставят на новый вопрос
- Когда редактируют старый вопрос с меткой-синонимом

Вот так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За эти два года "andoid" заменилось на [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) 22 раза:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если на вопросе есть и основная метка, и синоним, то останется только основная.

## Синоним не заменяется и не удаляется при назначении

Метка-синоним не удаляется и не заменяется на основную во всех вопросах сразу. Это страховка от ошибок.

Представьте: банда эйчаров пришла на ru.SO и синонимизировала метку [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) к [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).
Если при этом все [javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) заменятся на [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), придётся восстанавливать БД из бэкапа.

Сердце замерло, когда скриншот делал:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Полную замену может сделать модератор или сотрудник

если две метки идентичны по смыслу — как опечатки.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Вы видели вопрос, отредактированный до синонимизации

Вопрос, который вы видели, был задан до 9 сентября 2015 года и с тех пор ни разу не редактировался.

Если вы откроете его на редактирование и сразу же сохраните, метка-синоним заменится на основную.

Comment: "Лучше предложите синоним самостоятельно" - это могут только участники с >2500 репутации.

Comment: @VadimTagil там надо еще рейтинг по целевой метке иметь, так что репы недостаточно. Я предпочитаю пинговать кого-нибудь с ромбом в чате для целей синонимизации. Так быстрее.

Comment: @VadimTagil добавил подсказку про чат.

Comment: Вижу отсутствие перевода в скриншоте

Comment: @alexolut есть такое :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, уяснил,спасибо. `Представьте: банда эйчаров` - не,таких HR-ов я даже представлять не хочу,ибо это не банда HR-ов, а банда конченных синонимистов из планеты Нибиру. Значит как я понял,если я вижу в метках **опечатку**,которая уже синонимирована,то мне достаточно просто нажать на `править` к вопросу и не вводя никаких изменений её сохранить,чтобы опечатка автоматом исправилась на **правильную** метку ?

Answer (score 7):

> Хотелось бы подать тревогу для удаления

Метка удаляется через сутки, если с ней не связан ни один вопрос.
Если метка есть только на одном вопросе, она удалится с этого вопроса через шесть месяцев.

> cуществуют метки такие как интернет,где капсом написано *не использовать*

Это метки с долгой историей, порой содержащие вопросы, которые сами по себе стали оффтопиком. Но их сложно зачистить разом со всех вопросов, поэтому такая полумера.

Answer (score 5):

> Хотелось бы подать тревогу для удаления этой метки, но, видимо, такой функции нет.

Эти вопросом вы почти попали! Удаления меток рассматриваются здесь, на Мете, в метке [удаление-метки](/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8). Я добавил её в ваш вопрос.

> Но с этой меткой всего один вопрос на ru.stackoverflow, вряд ли кто-то в поисковике будет вбивать "Ошибка с интерлиньяжем".

Вы зря беспокоитесь. В текстах вопроса будет преобладать наиболее широко используемый термин, полнотекстовый поиск справится с выборкой материала. Но пока по этой метке есть всего один вопрос, сама необходимость в её существовании под вопросом, и мало шансов попасть сюда из поиска по этой теме.

Если же по одной теме образуется несколько меток, обычно одна из них делается синонимом другой. Предложить это для конкретных можно здесь же, на Мете. Если это что-то мелкое, можно [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

В контексте Stack Overflow вопрос, скорее всего, будет касаться интерлиньяжа в конкретной среде, и лучше указать эту среду ([css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), и т. д.).

> Или существуют метки такие как `интернет`,где капсом написано *не использовать* - зачем тогда эти метки держать на ресурсе ?

Тут по-разному бывает.

- Как правило, это временное компромиссное не-вполне-эффективное решение отвадить новичков от добавления в вопрос меток, которые никак не характеризуют вопрос.

  По-хорошему, да, такие метки не должны существовать, и создавать их не должно быть возможности ни у кого (кроме, ожидаемо, всесильной администрации). И, в теории, чёрный список меток, работающий именно так, [существует](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39824498#39824498). Но до добавления в него записей почему-то не доходит.

  Просто же уничтожить метку мало, поскольку у уничтоженной метки уничтожится и описание. Поэтому, в качестве временной меры, критическая масса метки (чтобы её не стёрло автоматикой) оставлена на ресурсе с угрожающим описанием (которое явно читают не все, но хоть кто-то).
- С меткой [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) же [особая ситуация](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5789/181100): это метка для общественных вопросов по сбору тематической литературы, которые по всем правилам являются оффтопиком, но всё равно регулярно появляются от новых участников.

  Мы надеемся добыть для неё специальную защиту, под которой метку не сможет добавлять в вопросы и удалять из них никто, кроме модераторов. Может, запрещающая красная плашка при попытке использовать метку убедит обратить внимание на описание метки.