# Предлагаю объединить некоторые метки

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

1. [text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text) и [текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82)
2. [memory](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory) и [память](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c)
3. [math](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) и [математика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: *(Боромир)* Нельзя просто взять и удалить метку.

Comment: @Nofate, но если очень хочется, то можно :-)

Comment: @Grundy без внесения в блэклист это бессмысленно

Comment: @Nofate, это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Долой костыль "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ"! Даёшь [нормальное решение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5789)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все переименования и удаления - в отдельные вопросы, неудобно обсуждать одновременно всё. Что касается первого списка на синонимизацию - не согласен с [img](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/img) и [изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - потому что первое - это html-элемент, а второе - всё что угодно про изображения. По крайней мере, я их так представляю на вид. Кстати, ещё объединение [ввод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) и [вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) кажется подозрительным.

Comment: Разбить по отдельным вопросам?

Comment: Да, но желательно [не пачку вопросов одновременно](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4343/178988). Давай по одному в день, например?

Comment: Без проблем) Этот вопрос удалять?

Comment: Предлагаю первую часть оставить.

Comment: А зачем? Дублирование получиться, если разбивать буду.

Comment: Думаю, 1, 2 и 5 можно пообъединять спокойно. Остальные надо почитать. Пусть будут одним вопросом.