# Метки "Математика" и "math" не должны быть равнозначны

Tags: предложение, метки, отмена-синонимов

Предлагаю не удалять метку math, а оставить её для вопросов, которые касаются одноименной библиотеки языка Си. Так как есть вопросы именно по этой библиотеки. А метку математика использовать как и решено для вопросов, касающихся математических проблем.

Comment: а кто-то удаляет? где?

Comment: Тогда уж вспомним, что и Python и Delphi (и другия ЯП) имеют аналогично названные библиотеки

Comment: @αλεχολυτ,  указано, что math   это старый тег для вопросов раздела "математика". Я предлагаю math использовать для вопросов, касающихся библиотеки Си mathю Можно для всех библиотек

Comment: Ее не удаляют, но метки уже синонимы: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7106/240512 Если синоним нужно убрать, напишите более подробно, почему. Обычно русское и английское написание одного и того же понятия должны быть синонимами.

Comment: Объясняю, почему это не синонимы: метка Математика, это вопросы, касающиеся именно математики (как науки) , т.е. вопросы по цифрам, геометрии, и другим разделам математики.
          А если метка math, это вопросы, касающие именно библиотеки math. Не вопросов математики, а использования библиотеки. И это прописать в вики по тегам.

Comment: По math решение было принято [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7106/176217)

Comment: Проблема в том, что эти множества вопросов сильно пересекаются, т.е. на типичный вопрос-домашку "помогите вычислить косинус на С++" можно навесить обе этих метки. Вы описываете, как должно быть, но не факт, что участники разберутся в этом тонком отличии. Можно создать метку [math.h], если есть особая нужда в классификации вопросов именно по этой библиотеке.

Comment: Совсем не очевидно, что метка [math] должна быть именно про библиотеку, тем более про библиотеку конкретного языка. А вот на enSO таки существует метка [math.h]

Comment: @andreymal, так для этого и существует описание меток. конечно, многие метки совершенно не очевидны, но! Если почитаешь аннотацию к ним все становится ясно. Все свои доводы я изложил. Уважаемое сообщество примет решение!

Comment: Описания меток никто не читает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: хм, я как раз всегда читаю ))) ...

Comment: Не тот волк, кто волк, а тот волк, кто метки читает! ауф

Comment: Зачем вы предлагаете правки с заменой [math] на [математика]? Эти метки **уже синонимы**. В старых вопросах может оставаться закешированная метка, но они обрабатываются сайтом как одно и то же. Вручную править ничего не надо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Синонимы созданы верно. Потому что [math](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) — это библиотека не только в [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). Нечто похожее есть в [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [delphi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi)... Да почти в любом языке. То есть в метку сваливаются вопросы, связанные с математикой. Поэтому и сотворили эти синонимы.

Если вы так любите библиотеку `math` в [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), то вы можете создать метку [вида [язык-библиотека]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12880/532877), то есть [math-c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math-c) (или [c-math](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-math)?)