# Предлагаю перестать принимать правки по замене необъединённых синонимов и заодно объединить синонимы [математика] и [math]

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток, предлагаемые-правки, нытьё, несущественные-правки

Один участник предлагает правки по замене необъединённых синонимов. Например, заменяют [math](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) на [математика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0). И иногда такие правки зачем-то принимают:

- [Раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/885303).
- [Два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/885325).
- [Три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/885275).
- [Четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/885158).

Замена синонимов абсолютно бессмысленна и если уж это делать, то автоматически. А принимая такие правки, мы как бы поощряем  эти действия.

Предлагаю:

1. Перестать принимать эти правки.
2. Объединить метки [математика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) и [math](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math). Чтобы этой ерунды в очереди больше не появлялось.

"За" это решение говорят следующие факторы:

- Метки сделаны синонимами, а [предложение отмены этой операции заминусовано в подвал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13080/532877).
- Часть этих правок отклонили ([пример1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/885274), [пример2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/885088)).
- Это уже просто бесит. Одну и ту же правку участник предлагал 3 раза, на третий раз попались невнимательные проверяющие, и они её приняли. Это говорит о том, что лучше раз и навсегда прекратить это и объединить синонимы.

[image: Скриншот истории одного сообщения]

**UPD**: для тех, кто не понял, что происходит: метки можно синонимизировать и не объединять. Тогда в новых вопросах синоним будет заменяться на оригинал, и при попытке искать вопросы по синониму, так же будет перекидывать на страницу с оригиналом. Но в старых вопросах с синонимом будет отображаться синоним. [Подробнее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6583/532877).

Comment: Вообще какая-то странная история, что такие замены уходят в очередь проверок. Похоже на баг.

Comment: Да надо просто слияние меток сделать и всё само заменится.

Comment: @Qwertiy объединение осмысленно, если это действительно одно и то же. Но судя по использованию - это не так.

Comment: @Qwertiy это одна из частей моего предложения :)

Comment: Что-то действительно странно, я принимал эти правки (или отклонял) когда метки уже были синонимизированы, они по моему и сейчас синонимы.

Comment: @чистов_n а что странного? Они [синонимы, но не объединены](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6583/532877).

Comment: @Зонтик не сразу, но понял.

Comment: Кстати, не "за одно", а "заодно".

Comment: @Глеб спасибо за замечание! Исправил.