# Не могу поменять причину закрытия вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Ребят я один не могу сменить причину закрытия вопроса или это системой запрещается?

Сегодня был такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426527/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5?noredirect=1#comment2542398_1426527). Я сначала поставил причину закрытия "Необходимо конкретизировать", т.к. там не вопрос, а целая статья была (да и осталась). Но после небольшой беседы выяснилось, что автор просто не дописал `?.` где надо было и у него теперь всё работает и ошибка не воспроизводится. Посчитал что вопрос всё равно надо закрыть, но уже по причине "Невоспроизводимая ошибка", но не смог. Либо я должен убрать голос, тогда не смогу заново проголосовать, а простыми кликами не меняется, хотя мышка отображается при наведении как на кликабельный элемент

Если это так и задумано, то это странно как по мне, после редактирования вопроса ведь, причина закрытся может спокойно поменяться. Если есть адекватные причины не допускать смену голоса, то буду рад прочитать :)

Но если вдруг это многим доставляет неудобство, то предлагаю разрешить смену голоса

Comment: например, чтобы думали прежде чем тыкать :-)

Comment: @Grundy Так я же не ошибся :) Т.е. в целом можно и нынешную причину оставить, вопрос всё равно гагантский. Просто после исправления ошибки другая причина стала более подходящей, потому захотел сменить причину. Но и в конце концов, можно просто ошибочно промахнуться, человеческий фактор никто не отменял :) Т.е. сама суть запрета не очень ясна, если честно. Чем плохим обернётся, если я смогу менять свою причину закрытия?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1564/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy Так вам модераторам можно тут всё?) Ладно, буду писать вам сообщения в следующий раз :)