# Разные причины закрытия

Tags: обсуждение

Я как-то читал в правилах, что для закрытия нужно 5 голосов и что приичиной будет выбрана та, за которую проголосовало большинство. Никак не смог найти где я это читал, но там после этого было сказано что-то типа "Да сейчас у возникнет вопрос, а что же будет если 5-о выберут 5 разных причин закрытия? Так стоп, тут остановитесь!" и ответ не был дан

Меня он всё время интересовал, но не нашёл ответа на этот вопрос. Так вот предлагаю чисто ради эксперемента закрыть этот вопрос по 5-ти разным причинам, просто чтобы посмотреть что будет :) И напишите кто за что проголосовал в комментариях, я просто подозреваю, что будет выбрана причина по такой схеме:

- Если среди голосовавших не будет ни одного модератора, то выберется причина участника с наибольшим кол-вом репутации

Но вполне может быть и рандомом. Модераторов попрошу не голосовать, а то одним махом закроете вопрос :)

Comment: От меня: Невозможно дать объективный ответ

Comment: несколько модераторов быть не может - модератор всегда одним голосом закрывает

Comment: «необходимо конкретизировать».

Comment: @Grundy А, я думал только на дубликаты это распостраняется. Видимо не то запомнил :)

Comment: Кто отметил "Непонятна суть вопроса"? Отпишись пожалуйста :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, дубликаты могут одним голосом закрывать пользователи с золотым знаком по метке

Comment: @Grundy Да, точно, спасибо :)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что на Мете всего 4 стандартные причины закрытия

Comment: @andreymal А как же дубликат? Я правильно понимаю, что Специфичную причину вы выбрали?

Comment: @EzioMercer не думаю, что дубликат можно считать «стандартной» причиной, так как у него слишком особенная механика работы

Comment: @andreymal Получается, можно будет выбрать только второй раз Специфичную причину и тогда он и будет выбран? Хотя всё равно остаётся вопрос о тексте, который будет отображаться как причина закрытия. Хотя чёрт его знает, жду дубликата :)

Comment: По-моему, сайт уже научился отображать несколько причин одновременно при равенстве голосов?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ни разу не видел, чтобы какой-то вопрос был закрыт по 5-ти разным причинам :) Если есть примеры, можешь поделиться  и я удалю этот вопрос

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M9wz.png - а чего эту никто не выбирал? Или это модераторский вариант?

Comment: @EzioMercer, ну по 5 вряд ли, а вот по 2 вроде встречал где-то...

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда получится так что два раза выбрали Специфичную причину и он однозначно выиграет. Но опять таки не знаю какой текст будет

Comment: @EzioMercer, думаешь, дубликат лучше?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну другой пятой причины нет же, мне больше не из чего выбирать

Comment: @Qwertiy На счёт твоего [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12059/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f?noredirect=1#comment52015_12059) - нет он не модераторский, мне он доступен

Comment: @Qwertiy вот пусть «эту» выберет какой-нибудь пятый участник

Comment: можно было и на англо-мете посмотреть. [What happens when everybody votes to close a question for a different reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138833/298597) и далее по ссылкам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу поменять причину закрытия вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12054/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: Закрыли: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYqCj.png

Comment: @Qwertiy Чёрт не надо было мне голосовать :) Удалять вопрос?

Comment: Всем участникам огромное спасибо :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, почему не надо?

Comment: @EzioMercer, подсветка просто как посещённой ссылки - я когда-то твой профиль открывал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Потому что я теперь не знаю, он выбрал эту причину потому что меня как автора выше приоритетом поставил или если бы вместо меня был бы другой, то результат был бы таким же :)

Comment: Да вообще непонятно, зачем у автора есть возможность голосовать за удаление. Ведь автор может просто взять и удалить без всякого голосования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эксперимент с вот таким распределением голосов

[image: скриншот истории]

показал, что закрытый вопрос отображается вот так:

[image: скриншот закрытия]